# JavaScript: set dropdown selected item based on option text

Tags: javascript

Say I have a dropdown list like this:

```
<select id="MyDropDown">
    <option value="0">Google</option>
    <option value="1">Bing</option>
    <option value="2">Yahoo</option>
</select>
```

and I want to set the selected value based on the option text, not the value with javascript. How can I go about doing this? For example, with c# I can do something like the example below and the the option with "Google" would be selected.

```
ListItem mt = MyDropDown.Items.FindByText("Google");
if (mt != null)
{
   mt.Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
var textToFind = 'Google';

var dd = document.getElementById('MyDropDown');
for (var i = 0; i < dd.options.length; i++) {
    if (dd.options[i].text === textToFind) {
        dd.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

A modern alternative:

```
const textToFind = 'Google';
const dd = document.getElementById ('MyDropDown');
dd.selectedIndex = [...dd.options].findIndex (option => option.text === textToFind);
```

Comment: It's better to check if option exists to avoid selection of empty option.

```function selectItem(selector, label) {
    const dropdown = document.querySelector(selector)
    const index = Array.from(dropdown.options).findIndex(option => option.label === label)

    if (!index) return

    dropdown.selectedIndex = index
  }

selectItem('#MyDropDown', 'Google')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can loop through the select_obj.options. There's a #text method in each of the option object, which you can use to compare to what you want and set the selectedIndex of the select_obj.

Answer (score 0):

This works in latest Chrome, FireFox and Edge, but not IE11:

```js
document.evaluate('//option[text()="Yahoo"]', document).iterateNext().selected = 'selected';
```

And if you want to ignore spaces around the title:

```js
document.evaluate('//option[normalize-space(text())="Yahoo"]', document).iterateNext().selected = 'selected'
```