# Javascript auto select from dropdown

Tags: javascript

I'm searching and searching and can not find anything exactly what I need.

So I need javascript, that will select option from dropdown, but not by the option value number, but name.

I have:

```
<select class="aa" id="local" name="local">
<option value="0">Cała Polska</option>
<option value="1">Dolnośląskie</option>
<option value="100">• Bolesławiec</option>
<option value="101">• Dzierżoniów</option>
<option value="102">• Głogów</option>
<option value="103">• Góra</option>
<option value="104">• Jawor</option>
<option value="105">• Jelenia Góra</option>
```

So I need to select `• Jawor` by name, not by id - it's the most important. How do I make it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989324/javascript-set-dropdown-selected-item-based-on-option-text

Answer (score 3):

For you is it like;

```js
var options = document.getElementsByClassName("aa")[0].options,
 name ="Jawor";

for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
   if(options[i].text.indexOf(name) > -1){
     options[i].selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<select class="aa" id="local" name="local">
    <option value="0">Cała Polska</option>
    <option value="1">Dolnośląskie</option>
    <option value="100">• Bolesławiec</option>
    <option value="101">• Dzierżoniów</option>
    <option value="102">• Głogów</option>
    <option value="103">• Góra</option>
    <option value="104">• Jawor</option>
    <option value="105">• Jelenia Góra</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `break` out of the loop once you find the match, there's no reason to keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Using `jquery` here. You can use the following function:

```
function selectFromDropdown(selector, text) {
  $(selector).find('option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == text) {
      $(selector).val($(this).val());
    }
  })
}
```

**A demo:**

```js
function selectFromDropdown(selector, text) {
  $(selector).find('option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == text) {
      $(selector).val($(this).val());
      return false;
    }
  })
}

//use the function

setTimeout(function() {
  selectFromDropdown('#local', '• Dzierżoniów')
}, 1000)
setTimeout(function() {
  selectFromDropdown('#local', '• Jawor')
}, 4000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="aa" id="local" name="local">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="0">Cała Polska</option>
  <option value="1">Dolnośląskie</option>
  <option value="100">• Bolesławiec</option>
  <option value="101">• Dzierżoniów</option>
  <option value="102">• Głogów</option>
  <option value="103">• Góra</option>
  <option value="104">• Jawor</option>
  <option value="105">• Jelenia Góra</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Here, it works wery well but it need to work in chrome console.. this is not

Comment: May be the console is not handling the special characters in your text properly. Can you first try using normal characters and see if it works?

Comment: You should break out of the `.each` loop when you find the matching element, there's no need to keep searching. Do that by returning `false`.

Comment: @Roy   It works very good but there's one problem. We have two selects. State and Local. When I set state by hand - clicking by mouse, then local (city) loads in second select. When I use your script, state is of course selected but nothing happens with the city. Is there something more we can do? Simulate mouse click maybe?

Comment: @grezluk If you have another function that's changing the city selector based on the state selection, call it after calling `selectFromDropdown()`.

Comment: @barmar - After or before? I guess you have to call the city `select` options creator before `selectFromDropdown` so that the options are plot first and then the value changes.

Comment: After. The city options creator uses the value of the state selector to know which cities to list.

Answer (score 0):

U need to Use onChange Event Handler ... for example

```
<select onchange="showSelected()">
```

Then write your script ...

```
<script>

function showSelected(){
    var s=document.getElementById('local');          //refers to that select with all options    
    var selectText=s.options[s.selectedIndex].text   // takes the one which the user will select
    alert(selectText)                                //Showing the text selected ...
}
</script>
```

Rest of your code is okay !

```
<select class="aa" id="local" name="local" onchange='showSelected'()>
<option value="0">Cała Polska</option>
<option value="1">Dolnośląskie</option>
<option value="100">• Bolesławiec</option>
<option value="101">• Dzierżoniów</option>
<option value="102">• Głogów</option>
<option value="103">• Góra</option>
<option value="104">• Jawor</option>
<option value="105">• Jelenia Góra</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You have it backwards. He doesn't want to show the text of the selected option, he wants to change which option is selected based on the text.

Comment: @Barmar  He wanted to change the selected option by the text inside options not by the value .
I used the alert() to just display , otherwise anybody can remove it and do what he/she wants .

Answer (score 0):

for chrome console use this

```
document.getElementById("id").selectedIndex = '3'; or
document.getElementById('id').value = 'BA';
```