# Set a dropdown to its default value when the dropdown is hide with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I have several dropdown (let's call them children) each shown with JavaScript when another dropdown (let's call him master) is selected with a specific value.
This JavaScript works perfectly fine. Now, I want that when a specific child has been set to a specific value, this child go back to its default value when another value of the master is selected.

My code so far:

```
  // On every 'Change' of the drop down with the ID "TailleSelector" call the displayTextField function
  document.getElementById("TailleSelector").addEventListener("change", displayTextField);
    function displayTextField() {
      // Get the value of the selected drop down
      var dropDownText =  document.getElementById("TailleSelector").value;
      // If selected text matches 'value', display the text field.
      if (dropDownText == "1 à 2") {
        document.getElementById("TailleBacGris12").style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        document.getElementById("TailleBacGris12").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("TailleBacGris12").value = '-';
      }
    }
```

The last getElementById (after the one which hides the first child dropdown) is not working, the value is not set to '-' when I change the master value...

Any hint on how I could make this work?

Thanks!

EDIT

While checking HTML as asked in the comment, I have found MY mistake Shame on me!

The ID call to hide the dropdown was one of a paragraph enclosing the select. Giving an ID to the select and calling it in the js above grant the right value to the select when it is hidden.

My bad folks and thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it is not working?  What are you doing in your code or during debugging that shows you that it is not working?

Comment: Is the default value always first one in the list? For all dropdowns?

Comment: Default is always the first and its value is '-'. If I test my dropdowns the child hidden with a selected value then shown again keep that value.

Comment: just the last statement _last getElementById (after the one wich hide the first child dropdown) is not working_ can you add your html code too ?

Comment: You are assigning text to the value and that's not how you should set selected value to a dropdown. Have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989324/javascript-set-dropdown-selected-item-based-on-option-text

Comment: I edit with HTML source as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comment - assigning item text to the value of the dropdown is not the right way to select that item in the dropdown.

Here is the snippet with the sample - first button assigns text as you do in OP, the other searches for the item by text and than assigns its index to `.selectedIndex` property, which is the right way to do it.

```js
function click(){
  myDD.value="1";
}

function click2(){
  for (i=0;i<myDD.options.length;i++){
    if (myDD.options[i].text == "2"){
      myDD.selectedIndex = i;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="myDD">
<option selected>-</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="click()" value="Assign Text" />
<input type="button" onClick="click2()" value="Right way" />
```

P.S. when you have `id` specified for your element, there is no need to call `document.getElementById()` function, you can refer to it just by id as if it was declared variable.