# set default values for dependent dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, multipleselection

I have 2 dropdown selection where the 2nd dropdown depends on the first one. So if you choose a car from USA the 2nd dropdown will provide you either Tesla or Ford.

I'm trying to set a default value for Japan AND Nissan; so at the end of the script I placed:

```
 $(countryID).val('JAPAN');  //perfect! works great
```

and

```
$(carID).val('Nissan');   //Nope! doesnt work
```

My code is also on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fmcgn7L/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                                <select class="form-control input-sm" style="font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" id="select-country" name="selectTerminal1" ></select>
                                <small style="font-size:14px;color:red" id="terminals-error-id"></small>
                            </div>
                            
                        <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                                <select class="form-control input-sm" style="font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" id="select-car"  ></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and the script

```
    var countries = ['USA','JAPAN']
    
    const c1 = {'country':'USA', 'name':'Ford'};
    const c2 = {'country':'USA', 'name':'Tasla'};
    const c3 = {'country':'JAPAN', 'name':'Nissan'};
    const c4 = {'country':'JAPAN', 'name':'Toyota'};
    
    var cars = [c1,c2,c3,c4];

    const countryID      = '#select-country'
    const carID     = '#select-car'
    
    //dropdown  1: by country                   
    countries = Array.from(new Set(countries)).sort();
    $(countryID).append(new Option('-- Select Country --', -1, true, true));
    countries.forEach(country =>{
        $(countryID).append(new Option(country, country, true, true));
        $(carID).append(new Option('--all cars--', country, true, true));
    });

    //dropdown 2: by name (dependent on country)
    cars.forEach(item =>{
        const country = item['country'];
        const tName   = item['name'];
        $(carID).append(new Option(tName, country, true, true));
    });


    //dependency
    var $selectcar1 = $( countryID ),
        $selectcar2 = $( carID ),

        $options = $selectcar2.find( 'option' );

        $selectcar1.on( 'change', function() {
                            $selectcar2.html( $options.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
                        } ).trigger( 'change' );


    //default
    $(countryID).val('JAPAN');
    //$(carID).val('Nissan');
```

Comment: All your cars just have a value of JAPAN or USA - something funny about the way you're doing the cars dropdown...I think you need to rethink the logic a bit. Perhaps use a data attribute to associate the car with the country in the second dropdown if you need both to filter. If you inspect the dropdown element in the browser in your fiddle, you'll see the cars all have the same value, which won't really work out.

Comment: @Nikki9696 thanks for the pointer. Can you share how to inspect that element in the browser?

Comment: Run your fiddle, right click the element, and inspect?

Comment: BUt you are writing it on purpose here `$(carID).append(new Option('--all cars--', country, true, true));` - you then use this to filter onchange, so you can't JUST change that. You'd have to add something else to filter on.

Comment: @Nikki9696 ok I know how to inspect now (thanks) not sure I follow you on the above comment. Say I didn't right that line. How would I able to set a default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment asks how to do it if you didn't write the line causing the problem. Therefore, assuming you ONLY have control over the default, you can - fix the fact that your select isn't triggering change, and select the option by text, which frankly I don't even know how to do in jquery so here's vanilla script for it.

Credit [to this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47340778/456669)

```
//default
        $(countryID).val('JAPAN');
        $(countryID).trigger('change');
        let dd = document.getElementById('select-car');
        dd.selectedIndex = [...dd.options].findIndex (option => option.text === "Nissan");
```